# Increase Array Size Based on Total Numbers Entered

Tags: java, arrays

I have an issue for creating an array based on the total amount of numbers entered into the array.

Essentially the program is expected to work as the following: the user is prompted for n numbers to enter into an array. So until the user types '000' as their input, the user will be prompted for a new number.

Note: for this array, I do not want the user to input the amount of numbers they want to enter for the array size. Instead, I want the user to continue inputting random numbers until '000' has been inputted, then, the total amount of numbers that has been entered into the array, is the size of such array.

For example: this would work if we have int array[] = {1, 2, 4, 6}, this will automatically set array size to 4, without actually explicitly declaring the array size as 4 elements. Similarly, with my code, I want it where the numbers that the user enters is added to the array, and then the array size is automatically given from the amount of numbers the user has entered like above.

It is important to note that we do ***not*** know the length of the array until the user has entered all n numbers.

I have attempted a skeleton, but it returns a cannot find symbol error:

Code:

```
//Array Code           
import java.util.*;

class setArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int stopInput = 000;
        int number;

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        number = input.nextInt();

        while(number != stopInput) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            number = input.nextInt();
            int array[] = {number};
        }       
       System.out.print("Array size: " + array.length);
    } // Main brace
} // Class brace
```

> ```
> setArray.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
>     System.out.print("Array Size: " + array.length);
>       symbol:    variable array
>       location:  class setArray
>     1 error
> ```

Comment: I guess this is a homework and you may not simply use a list?

Comment: This is not homework. I am new to programming, so I never assumed to use a 'List'.

Comment: Ok, no offense intended! Then I'd go with a list - I guess you can just pick one of the answers here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors here. The first is understanding why you get your immediate error. The variable `array` is declared within the scope of the while loop. It can not be seen outside of this loop. That is why the compiler is complaining.

The second is that the size of the array (if declared outside of the loop) will always be 1. From my understanding of what you have written as an attempt to solve the problem you have describe shows that you are not tackling the problem correctly.

While you don't known the the final length of the array to be entered; you do need to store the values entered (my inference) to populate the final array. To store the value entered by the user you need a list that will grow with the input.

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();

while (number != stopInput) {
  System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
  values.add(Integer.valueOf(input.nextInt()));
}

Integer[] array = values.toArray(new Integer[values.size()]);
```

Comment: What is values.toArray doing? Whenever I add that to it, it causes the following error message: java 18: error: no suitable java method found for toArray(int[]) along with a large not applicable error message the size of two response boxes.

Comment: @Baleroc, I have correct an error in my code; `int` should have been `Integer`. The `values.toArray()` method converts the `List<Integer>` (which resizes dynamically) to an `Integer[]` (which has a fixed size); i.e. convert a list to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the compilation error is because the `array` variable is not visible from the `System.out.println` line. This is because it's declared inside the while loop, so is only visible inside the while loop.

To make it visible to the whole method, declare it before the while loop.

Secondly, arrays cannot be resized. You declare an array to be a certain size, and you cannot add or remove elements.

My suggestion would be to use an `ArrayList`. Declare one before your loop, and add the new number inside the loop. After the loop, the size should be how many numbers were entered.

Finally, there's no difference between `000` and `0`. Is `0` a valid input number?

Comment: You're correct. 000 and 0 made no different. So I have changed the input from 000, to 012 for simplicity.

Comment: But that means you can't use the number 12. Adding 0's to the front of a number makes no difference.

Comment: Would you suggest to convert it to a String, then parse int each String to an integer then if stopInput = # then inputNumbers = false

Comment: You already use a Scanner. Scanner has a method called hasNextInt() which might be of use...

Comment: Hmm, someone seems to have downvoted this. Any suggestions for improving the answer will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
List<Integer> array=new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(number != stopInput) {
      System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
      number = input.nextInt();
      array.add(number);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for java.util.ArrayList - this is the array that doesn't have a fixed size and is growing as you add values to it automatically under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because you are creating the array only within the scope of the while loop. You need to create it outside the loop. Secondly, standard arrays are not dynamic, so you would need to either set the size and increase it as needed, or just simply use an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Psuedo:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>()
...
while(not stop number)
  list.add(number)
...
print(list.size())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use an Array, here is how you can do it

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    STOP_ENTRY = "000";
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    entry = "";
    while(true){
        System.out.print("Enter #: ");
        String tempS = scan.nextLine();
        if(tempS.equals(STOP_ENTRY)) break;
        else entry += tempS + ":";
    }
    String[] split = entry.split(":");
    int[] intArray = new int[split.length];
    System.out.println("Length of created intArray = " + intArray.length); //length of created array

    for(int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++){
        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
        System.out.println("intArray[" + i + "] => " + String.valueOf(intArray[i]));
    }

}
```

I would recommend an ArrayList, as it dynamically changes is size when you add an element, but do whatever you'd like.

An important note, this does not handle any malicious entry that you might not want (characters, symbols), and will error if they are entered, something you can easily add if you need